# Xcode 6 change View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, view, controller

I have two Views Controller, one is called `Main` and the other is called `InserirCodigoViewController`. And I have a `int` called `contarParaMudar. My code is:

```
 -(IBAction)ok:(id)sender { 
    if (completeLevel == true) {

        contarParaMudar = 1;

    } else if (contarParaMudar == 1) {

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboar = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboar instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InserirCodigoViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

But I would like the following: when the user opens the app and `completeLevel = true` , the iphone must load directly `InserirCodigoViewController`

What can I do?? (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: Does that solve your Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just add in MainVC the `viewDidAppear` Method, and perform the code you posted inside it...

To store the BOOL use NSUserDefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"completeLevel"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Load it

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"completeLevel"] == YES) {
    //load your VC
}
```

Comment: Hmm viewDidAppear is getting called every time the view appears... Maybe you close this view and completeLevel is still true?

Comment: Can you send me your source code by email? I think this would be the best way to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

*I am doing something similar in my project, I am saving completeLevel into NSUserDefaults and   then based on its value deciding the view controller to show in my appdelegate*

Or you can use  viewDidAppear as suggested by Neo

Answer (score 0):

Set `completeLevel` to `YES` when a level is completed, for the first time make it `NO`. You can store `BOOL` values in `NSUserDefaults` like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"completeLevel"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

> As you said "when the user opens the app and completeLevel = true , the iphone must load directly InserirCodigoViewController"

For this in your AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you have to do this:

```
BOOL isLoggedIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"completeLevel"] == YES;
NSString *storyboardId = isLoggedIn ? @"Main" : @"InserirCodigoViewController";
self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];
```

Hope this helps... :)